# Como usar Kivy com Python 3.4.3 no Mac

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Como posso usar o Kivy com o Python 3.4.3 no OS X?
Só funciona com o Python 2.7

Comment: Cara, simplesmente não tem como. Você viu isso em algum lugar? No próprio site do Kivy fala que em osx só funciona com 2.7.

Answer (score 1):

Funciona no Python 3.7 também como informa no site.

[Download Kivy 1.9.1 - osx . python 3.7](https://web.archive.org/web/20160729012956/https://kivy.org/downloads/1.9.1/Kivy-1.9.1-osx-python3.7z)

Answer (score 0):

Infelizmente, você só pode utiliza-lo no Mac com a versão 2.7 do Python!